# RadioButton - using different formulas

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button, radio-group

I've just started out and want to make a program to make my life easier. I'll need to perform some math operations. For that, I need 2 radio buttons: 2-month and 3-month:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFA24D"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_2m"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2 month"
        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_3m"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3 month"
        android:checked="false" />
</RadioGroup>
```

I want to execute one piece code (math formulas and stuff) when 2 month is selected and other code (other formulas) when 3 month is selected. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also have a 'salary' button. So I choose 2 or 3 month, type in the number of students and the number of missed lessons and then press 'salary' - it must give me the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a few 'cascading' if statements in your code.
First, you need to get a reference to the view defined in your layout (using `findViewById(R.id.radio_2m)` etc), then you can use `radioButton.isChecked()` which will tell you whether the radio button is checked.

```
if(radiobutton1.isChecked()) {
    // The first radio button was checked
}
else {
    // The other radio button was checked.
}
```

This works because the RadioGroup that you have wrapped both radio buttons in automatically makes sure only 1 of its child radio buttons are checked at a time. You should also set one of the radio buttons to checked in your xml, since default there should be one selected.